# Текст бегущей строки

Tags: javascript

Как текст бегущей строки вынести в отдельный файлик stroka.js ?

Comment: Не профессионально называть файл stroka.js. Лучше подойдет string.js. Никогда не называй переменные или ресурсы или классы русскими словами.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="stroka.js"></script>
```

И в stroka.js задаете текст строки на javascript. А вообще, могли бы и сами погуглить "javascript отдельный файл".

Answer (score 1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="stroka.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

  <marquee behavior="alternate" direction="left" bgcolor="#ffcc00" id="string">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </marquee>

 </body>
</html>
```

В string.js

```
window.onload = function
{
    var str_text = "text stroki";  // текст строки
    document.getElementById('string').innerHTML = str_text;
}
```